# Unknown primary key for table in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am getting unknown primary key for table, I am not able to judge why this is coming
My Table has primary key

CustomerNote

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: customer_notes
#
#  id                       :integer          not null, primary key
#  title                    :string
#  company_id               :integer
#  customer_id              :integer          not null
#  user_id                  :integer

Customer Note Version
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: customer_note_versions
#
#  id                       :integer          not null, primary key
#  title                    :string
#  user_id                  :integer
#  company_id               :integer
#  customer_note_id         :integer
#
#Foreign Keys
# fk_rails_...  (customer_note_id => customer_notes.id)
```

CustomerNoteVersion

```
belongs_to :customer_note
validates :title, :user_id, :customer_note_id, presence: true
```

CustomerNote

```
has_many :customer_note_versions, dependent: :destroy
validates :title, presence: true
```

I am trying to call 
CustomerNote.new.customer_note_versions
Its throwing error on test console

> ActiveRecord::UnknownPrimaryKey: Unknown primary key for table
>   customer_notes in model CustomerNote.

Comment: to have `CustomerNote.customer_note_versions` the customernote should be already saved in database.... you are creating a active record with the id blank using `CustomerNote.new` . id will be filled only after the record is saved.

Comment: id should be autogenerated right

Comment: main problem is with rspec

Comment: `CustomerNote.new` will create a  record with id=>nill , id will be assigned automatically when saved

Comment: try to call the CustomerNote.customer_note_versions with a record already saved in db.

Comment: @KunalVashist Please share RSpec code if that's the main problem